# jsp mysql inserting error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

this is y inserting syntax

```
String add="INSERT INTO time_table VALUES("+coursename+"','"+coursecode+"','"+days+"','"+year+"','"+dep+"','"+time+"','"+hall+"','"+lecturer+"','"+credithours+"')";
```

ERROR

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','5','2','2','8','1','9','PA','2')' at line 1
```

that is what am receiving as an error.

Comment: What is your time_table table structure? If you do not specify the column names it is expected that you are passing data for all columns in the same order as they are defined in the database.

Answer (score 3):

I think correct version of your query is this :

```
"INSERT INTO time_table VALUES('"+coursename+"','"+coursecode+"','"+days+"','"+year+"','"+dep+"','"+time+"','"+hall+"','"+lecturer+"','"+credithours+"')";
```

you forgot `'` in beginning of `+coursename+`

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever use this way, it can cause Syntax error, ot SQL Injection, you have to use PreparedStatement instead for example :

```
String add = "INSERT INTO time_table VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?)";

try (PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(add)) {

    insert.setString(1, coursename);
    insert.setString(2, coursecode);
    insert.setString(3, days);
    insert.setString(4, year);
    insert.setString(5, dep);
    insert.setString(6, time);
    insert.setString(7, hall);
    insert.setString(8, lecturer);
    insert.setString(9, credithours);

    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

**Note** if your attributes are int or float or date or ... in your table, then you have to use the correct set, for example if the year is an in you can use `insert.setInt(4, year);` instead.

---

Your real problem is in your query you miss `'` here :

```
INSERT INTO time_table VALUES('" + coursename + "'
//----------------------------^
```

Comment: In fact you guys are soo helpful. May God bless you.